# Saving a UIView whose size 10000x10000 to the album

Tags: ios, image, uiview, save, photos

I have a 10000x10000 UIView and want to save its image to the photos in iOS. However, while saving the image like below, it cannot keep its native resolution (i.e. 10000x10000) and I obtain a low resolution image.

```
   UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.opaque, 0);
   view.drawViewHierarchyInRect(view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: false);
   var image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
   UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
   UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);
```

How can I save my UIView at its native resolution? Thanks a lot...

Comment: What do you mean by `it cannot keep its native resolution`?  Did you get an error?

Comment: No, I didn't any error. When I open the image in Photos app and zoom it in, the image becomes blurry unlike in my application. In short, UIView is saved at low resolution.

Comment: Wait... How do you have a 10000x10000 UIView?? If it's displaying within your screen in its entirety, it must have been reduced.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with these line:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.opaque, 0);
view.drawViewHierarchyInRect(view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: false);
```

You're setting the image's drawing context to a size of view.bounds.size then taking a snapshot of the view, so `image` is going to be a snapshot of your screen equal to your screen size. If you don't want to reduce your image, then don't. Remove those first four lines, get the image from your `UIImageView` (or however you're displaying your image), then simply save the image, ex:

```
var image = imageView.image
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);
```

Comment: Oh just saw that the image is an image of your 10000x10000 View so my answer only explains the problem, not the solution.  As I wrote in my comment under your question: How do you have a 10000x10000 UIView?? If it's displaying within your screen in its entirety, it must have been reduced.

Comment: I use ScrollView so that the screen does not display entire view.

Comment: @birsorubircevap Gotcha. Well your screencap is currently the size of the screen. Are you able to capture your entire scrollview contents with your current code?

Comment: @birsorubircevap If so, I'd recommend replacing the instances of view.bounds with the scrollview's content biew's bounds.

Comment: No way. Blank screen is saved.

Comment: @birsorubircevap what "no way"? No way to my question? Are you able to capture your entire scrollview contents w your current code?

Comment: OK. I think I'm about to find the problem. There is maximum image size in terms of pixels in iOS. If an image exceeds the limit, it is subsampled. Now, I will check that my finding is really true. Thanks for your concern.